# Azure AD B2C Create User with the Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I know that we can create users in the Azure AD B2C using the Graph Api.
But can we use it in a mobile app (like Android or iOS) and automatically connect the user once the registration (it means to get the tokens (id & refresh) at the end of registration) is done ?

thanks in advance

Comment: A sign up policy will create a user for you automatically after the user completes registration, you shouldn't need to call Graph. Is there a reason sign up policies don't work for you?

Comment: We want to implement a sign-up form on both Android & iOS application and we would like to implement this with native screen (du to the limitation of customization on the webview). So that's why we were thinking about Graph API to create the user.

Comment: Makes sense. Unfortunately right now you can't call the Graph API securely from a mobile client. It's an architectural limitation were trying to remove.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't call the Graph API using tokens you receive on a mobile client right now.

The only workaround is to have your client call some web service you run, and then have the web service create users using the pattern described at aka.ms/aadb2c (look for Graph API in the navigation tree)

Comment: OK thanx, sounds like that we will have to use the sign up policy and webview... do you know when the full customization for sign-up and sign-in will be available ?